# Where should I go?

Tags: cipher

An old friend of mine just sent me an email:

---

Hey man!

Long time no see! How are you?

I had to relocate recently because of my job...

New country, new city, no friends... Need somebody like you to hang out with!

If you'll find some free time, come and visit me!

I remember you like puzzling, so I'll give you a challenge!

I am currently based in

> $9945$
>
> $10850$
>
> $12942$

I hope I didn't make it too difficult. There's $3$ steps to decipher it:

> 1) change the system
>
> 2) visualise
>
> 3) translate

Flight tickets & drinks are on me if you'll figure it out until the weekend!

Regards

K

---

Help me find the name of the city hidden in those numbers!

HINT 1:

> For the first step, you have to change the numerical system

HINT 2:

> Binary

Comment: Maybe try changing to hexadecimal or binary?

Comment: @DanielScott You're right for the first step! You have to convert the numbers into another number system :)

Comment: Huh. I tried base 26 yesterday and it didn't seem to do anything useful. I should have been less lazy and tried some more.

Comment: aha! `⛙⩢㩞`  oops that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Binary doesn't seem to make a nice bitmap (even after rearranging in various ways)

Comment: (oops, hit enter before I meant to) ... which is a pity since "visualise" rather suggests something of that kind. Base 26 yields OSNQBITDU, which is an anagram of QUIT BONDS and B NOT SQUID and SQUIB DON'T and probably other slightly evocative things, but I'm not seeing a city there. Base 256 and treating each number as two characters in some standard encoding doesn't seem to do anything useful either. Base 36 gives 7O9 8DE 9ZI which doesn't look useful either.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan binary is right. You just need to "visualise" it different :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to

> Vilnius, Lithuania

"Change the System"

> to binary.

this gives you

> 10011011011001
> 10101001100010
> 11001010001110

"Visualize" and "Translate"

> using Braille. Stack the three binary numbers and separate into pairs of columns, forming 3x2 blocks.
> 10
> 10 = V
> 11
> 01
> 10 = I
> 00
> 10
> 10 = L
> 10
> 11
> 01 = N
> 10
> 01
> 10 = I
> 00
> 10
> 00 = U
> 11
> 01
> 10 = S
> 10

Comment: You can use <br> to mark end-of-lines in spoiler blocks

Comment: you have to add two spaces at the end of the line, so its like a line break :)

Comment: more visuals and I will mark it :)