# Upside-Down Map

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7352/79067). The streets and addresses are fictional.</sub>

---

It's [your friend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/35913/79067) again; they've moved to a new address (you already know city and country), and they've sent you another email:

> Hey! You were pretty quick solving the last puzzle I gave you, so here's another one.
>
> I just got a promotion and a raise at work, and you know your birthday is coming up, so if you solve *this* one, I'll get you that VR gaming system you've been raving about the past 3 months ;-). You can get it early if you stop by!
>
> I've moved to a new address in this section of town. Can you tell me which building it is?
>
> [image]
>
> Hope to see you soon!
>
> K

You wonder where they got such an incomplete  map. Nevertheless, you'd like to see them again, and that gaming system sounds nice, so you set to work...

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit this into the [meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7353/79067). Would someone mind doing it for me? Thanks!

Comment: ^ Done :) (And yes, I copy-pasted the spelling of your username...!)

Comment: @Stiv Thanks! I feel like I'm going to regret that username some day... I don't even know how to pronounce it :D.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest you make a beeline for building number:

> **EIGHTY FOUR**

To work this out:

> do what the title suggests, and **turn this map upside down**! When we do that, we can notice that along the named streets, some of the building shapes appear to be very blocky letters spelling out their names:
>
>  [image: Upside down map, hidden letters shown]
>
>  If we focus only on the shapes of those buildings with numbers (which are all multiples of [the magic number, 42](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/42), purely as an Easter egg...) and arrange them in numerical order, the corresponding letters spell out **EIGHTY FOUR**!
>
>  So your friend lives in 84 Main Street, just west of Green Avenue. (Or, wait, is that *east*? I guess we really need to know which way up this map goes!!)

Comment: _Dang_ that was quick. Between the posting and the solving, I only just had time to eat lunch! Good job! Here's +1 and a check mark.

Comment: To extend the Easter egg, let's also note that rot13(rvtugl-sbhe vf nyfb n zhygvcyr bs sbegl-gjb).